# Converting byte to image and image to byte using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, image, typeconverter

currently i am working with ASP.NET and C# to store image into MySQL (using blob datatype). I'm storing it successfully into database, but now problem is, How can I retrieve that `byte[]` to image format ?

FUNCTION: `code to convert byte[] to image`

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms); --> here gives me error as `parameter is not valid`
        return returnImage;

    }
```

retieved as datatable...

```
if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            byteArrayToImage((byte[]) dt1.Rows[0]["PortfolioSlideImages"]);
            //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dt1.Rows[0]["PortfolioSlideImages"]);
            //Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            //return returnImage;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function,

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     Image returnImage = null;
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
     {
         returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     }
     return returnImage;
}
```

[for more info, visit this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv)

Comment: i tried it but `Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);` not supporting that is `Image.FromStream(ms)`. I have included 2 dlls 1st is using `system.IO` an 2nd is `using system.drawing` . Any idea why not supporting this function in my code ???
`