# .net core: How to convert byte array to image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to convert byte array to image. I searched a lot of posts in StackOverFlow and found the code below.

```
public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms); //  <-- Error here
    return returnImage;
}
```

But I get an error in **Image.FromStream** is *'Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream'* and couldn't find any info on how to fix this.
There is a user who [had the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792175/converting-byte-to-image-and-image-to-byte-using-c-sharp) as me more than 9 years ago but still no answer.
I found a way is:

```
public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); // <-- Add System.Drawing. here
    return returnImage;
}
```

And a way:

```
public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); // <-- Add System.Drawing. here
    return returnImage;  //  <-- Error here
}
```

But both ways gives a new error as: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'Repository.Entities.Image'**.
This is my *Image file* in *Repository.Entities*:

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? IdObj { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public sbyte? Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

How to fix it? Looking forward to receiving an answer.

Comment: Your `Image` class is totally unrelated to the `System.Drawing.Image` class.

Comment: You are confused betweeen System.Drawing.Image <- Generic Type for dealing with (let's say) bitmap data,   'Repository.Entities.Image <- your App specific data structure (without any place to hold a Image data inside, only a Url) So you can´t do it

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve. Why are you looking into System.Drawing anyway?

Comment: Apologies if my question is rather silly and unclear. I'm confused betweeen _System.Drawing.Image_ and _Repository.Entities.Image_ . The answer below can help me understand and solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ByteArrayToImage` function definition you are saying that you will return a class instance of type `Repository.Entities.Image` but within the function body you are returning a class instance of type `System.Drawing.Image`.

You can add another property to your `Repository.Entities.Image` as `System.Drawing.Image` and set it within the function:

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? IdObj { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public sbyte? Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public System.Drawing.Image MyImage{get; set; }
}

public Repository.Entities.Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); 
    return new Repository.Entities.Image {
        MyImage= returnImage
    }
}
```

Now you can use `.MyImage` property (which is of type `System.Drawing.Image`) of your own Image class  (which if of type `Repository.Entities.Image`) in your code.

Additionally, I always prefer to name my classes different than predefined classes (such as Image, Document, Path...etc). If you are planning to have conflicting names, it is a good practice to use full namespaces to prevent confusion of classes.